# How to migrate linux kernel to a higher kernel version

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, upgrade, patch

I am working on some linux kernel modules & my current kernel is `3.8`, I want to upgrade it to kernel `3.10`.

I thought of two ways to do it:

1. Either check out a separate `3.10` branch and then merge it with my current `3.8` branch.
2. Or patch `3.8` with `3.9` patch and then patch it with `3.10` patch (patches available on kernel.org are a diff of the current and the previous version, what I believe)

Which approach should I follow? Is there a better way to do it?

I am using git as the version control software.

Comment: AFAIK for your modules to work you need to replace the kernel of your system too, e.g.,If you compile your module against the version 3.10 of the kernel, then your system need to run that version too.

Comment: 1) Find the version closest to your base which has a 3.10 available.  2) Diff your current tree against that tree's 3.8.  3) Apply your changes to that version of 3.10, automatically where possible and manually *including to the extent of porting to new mechanisms where needed*.  4) Resume forward development progress

Comment: rendon : Yes, I'm replacing the entire kernel.
@ChrisStratton : Thanks for the suggestion, I am doing somthing similar to what you suggested, I have downloaded the kernel tree, I have identified the version closest to my base which has 3.10 available. Then I will take a diff of this pristine 3.8 & 3.9, will apply it to my 3.8, then again the same thing with pristine 3.9 & 3.10. Hopefully it would work.

Comment: That's probably going to be a vastly larger and less uninformative diff compared to diffing your private version against the upstream.  A side benefit of the latter is that you'll discover what changes from the upstream standard you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in terms of git you may choose either way.

You may take v3.8 sources, create a separate branch (called, say, my_modules), apply your changes in that branch, commit them. Then you have to merge that branch with the actual kernel sources (I would suggest with upstream `master` but you may choose any other point (commit) in the kernel development history): `git merge <chosen-branch-o-tag-o-commit>`. At this point you may have to resolve merge conflicts if any, update your module to the new kernel internal API etc and then commit the merged state. See `git merge --help` and other relevant git documentation. Now you have your changes adapted to the chosen version of kernel and may see the diff between upstream kernel and the patched one: `git diff <chosen-branch-o-tag-o-commit> HEAD`. The resulting commit picture would look like this:

```
A -    ...   - B
 \             \
   D1 - D2... - M
```

where A is the initial branch point (3.8 kernel), B is the commit you merged with (a newer kernel), D1..DN are your driver's commits and M is the merge.

Alternatively you may also use another approach called rebasing. In this case you "transplant" your initial commits sequence to the new chosen root: `git rebase -i B`. Then git will try to re-apply the whole sequence D1...DN to the new root B iteratively. Please note that on *each* step 1...N you may get a conflict which you need to resolve and then continue the rebasing process with `git rebase --continue`. At the [successful] end you will get a *new* commit sequence D'1 - D'N growing from B:

```
A - ... - B
             \
              D'1 - .... D'N
```

Please note that technically D'1...D'N while looking /similar/ to your original D1...DN are different.  They have their own commit time, may have slightly different patch text etc. Depending on your needs they may or may not be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated ans, after some discussion and suggestions here, I think I'll go with the diff & patch approach.

Comment: In fact diff & patch approach is simply inconventient. It's like cultivating a field with a horse and a hand plow while everybody else use tractors and harvesters. You will have to repeat all boring actions for each version kernel you like to update your module to. But certainly you to decide.

Comment: Turned out my driver had very minimal changes when ported to higher kernel. So, the easiest thing for me was to create a patch and apply on to the latest kernel version. Thanks for the insight though!